# Is it possible to Merge two multimodule project jacoco report

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-plugin

We want to update the gitHub pr with jacoco coverage value. Our repo structure is like below,

```
  Function1
   |___ Module1
   |___ Module2
   |___Function1JacocoAggregatereport
  Function2
   |__ ModuleA
   |__ ModuleB
   |__ Function2JacocoAggregatereport
```

We need to merge the aggregate report of Function1 and Function2 and update the value as comment in gitHub pr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge report.xml generated by jacoco to one report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676287/merge-report-xml-generated-by-jacoco-to-one-report)