# merge report.xml generated by jacoco to one report

Tags: android, jacoco, android-jacoco

I have an android project with many modules, we run our unit tests in PRs just for changed modules, so our generated jacoco report is at the module level, but now I need a aggregated report,
is it possible to merge all report.xml after generating?
so far I found a few ways that you can create an aggregated report for the whole project, but since I don't run my unit tests for all modules in the project for each PR is there any way to create an aggregated report for some modules in a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacoco provides [`report-aggregate`](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html) goal to generate a merged reports from multiple Maven modules. Check the [documentation](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html) for more details.